# screen scrape using cURL only gets header and footer

Tags: php, html, curl

I've been challenged to screen scrape this website. It works with plenty of other sites, but for some reason only fetches the header and footer of this one (http://www.coast-stores.com/SOPHIE-DRESS/Dresses/coast/fcp-product/2224724715)

```
function get_url($url) {
$curl = curl_init();

$header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
$header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
$header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
$header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
$header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
$header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
$header[] = "Pragma: ";

$cookie = '/cookies.txt';
$timeout = 30;




curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,             $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,       'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,      $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING,        'gzip,deflate'); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,     true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER,         'http://google.co.uk/');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,         20); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,  $timeout );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,       $cookie);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,      $cookie);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,  true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,  false );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,  false );    # required for https urls
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,       30 );

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);

$responseHTML   = curl_exec($curl);
$response       = curl_getinfo( $curl );

curl_close($curl); // close the connection

//return $html; // and finally, return $html


if ($response['http_code'] == 301 || $response['http_code'] == 302)
{
    ini_set("user_agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1");

    if ( $headers = get_headers($response['url']) )
    {
        foreach( $headers as $value )
        {
            if ( substr( strtolower($value), 0, 9 ) == "location:" )
                return get_url( trim( substr( $value, 9, strlen($value) ) ) );
        }
    }
}

if (
    (preg_match("/>[[:space:]]+window\.location\.replace\('(.*)'\)/i", $content, $value) 
    || preg_match("/>[[:space:]]+window\.location\=\"(.*)\"/i", $content, $value))
    && $javascript_loop < 5
)
{
    return get_url( $value[1], $javascript_loop+1 );
}
else
{
    return $responseHTML; //array( $content, $response );
}
}

// uses the function and displays the text off the website
$text = get_url($_GET['url']);
echo $text;
```

Any ideas why it's not fetching the main content? Could it be that the content is delivered once the HTML has been displayed?

Example of the script running here: http://www.mattfacer.com/scraping/scraping2.php?url=http://www.coast-stores.com/SOPHIE-DRESS/Dresses/coast/fcp-product/2224724715

Try it with any other website and it seems to work!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: That URL doesn't even work in my browser.  I get a 301 to the homepage every time.  I can't even navigate to that page manually.  I don't think it exists anymore.  Pretty hard to scrape a URL that's been removed.

Comment: Works fine if you try a URL that actually exists: http://www.mattfacer.com/scraping/scraping2.php?url=http://us.coast-stores.com/Coast-Allure-Maxi/dp/B004SFF0V2

Comment: that's strange - I wonder if their site uses some sort of country check on the IP address? The server is in the states. I assume you are too - as I too can see the full page with the dollar price. Yet I can see the URL in my example, but not the content. All very strange.

Comment: tip: You don't have to check for server redirect manually. You can set the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option and let curl do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Checked out the url but it's being redirected back to the home page. Can you give us steps on how to get to the page that your looking for? Either the page disappeared or the site uses cookies to allow access to certain portion of the site.